# Using Nodejs to access ssh commands

Tags: node.js, shell

I am using latest **NodeJS(12.X)** version in my Windows desktop.

I used remote of **Cisco** routers using putty and execute few commands there.

Now, I need to execute these commands (like show, run version) in my **Cisco** routers using Nodejs application. I need to write those output from routers in to my base machine in `.txt` format or need to show it in console.

I already tried `simple-ssh` and `remote-exec` but its not successful.

Can anyone help me here with sample code, that would be Great!..
Thanks.

Comment: Added formatting to make more readable and answerable

Comment: Give node-ssh a shot, here is a quick tutorial: https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-to-ssh-using-nodejs